# webDav server edit

Tags: webdav

I do have access to a web-dav server, and I configured it using "Add network Places" in my local XP machine. Can anyone let me know what tools are available if I would like to edit files on server.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can edit Microsoft Office files on your server if you have Microsoft Office installed on you client XP machine. Note that your server must be Class 2 compliant and must be located on site root: http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only

If you [map a drive](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/access/map_drive) to WebDAV server than any application will be able to read and edit files on your server.